# Get the same day of certain week using moment.js or date.js

Tags: javascript

How could i get a day in certain week from a date using moment.js or date.js?

example :

```
var x = "some date";
var y =  3; //this is a day value (1=sunday - 7=saturday)
```

what is the date of the 'y' of the same week based on 'x' ?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/